# Why is wx.Yield() apparently not yielding under Windows

Tags: python, wxpython

I have cut the guts out of a little app to demonstrate this behaviour.   Under osx, this works how I expect: when you press the button, it prints "Asked to start work", then a message box appears, and things pause until the OK button is pressed, after which it starts printing "yielding" and the GUI remains moderately alive.

```
import wx
import time

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800, 700))
        self.tabbed = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=(wx.NB_TOP))

        self.running = RunningPane(self.tabbed)
        self.submissions = SubmissionPane(self.tabbed, self.running)

        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.submissions, "Submit Job")
        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.running, "Running Jobs")
        self.Show()


class SubmissionPane(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, run_pane):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.run_pane = run_pane

        self.buttonGo = wx.Button(self, -1, "Submit", pos=(290,170))
        self.buttonGo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSubmit)

        self.Show()

    def OnSubmit(self, event):
        self.run_pane.StartWork()
        print "requested work start"
        wx.MessageBox('Job Submitted')
        print "displayed message box"

class RunningPane(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.running_log = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, pos=(35, 210), size=(720,400))
        self.Show()


    def StartWork(self):
        print "Asked to Start Work..."
        wx.CallAfter(self.DoTheWork)
        print "registered the CallAfter"

    def DoTheWork(self):
        print "Actually starting work"
        self.running_log.WriteText("doing..."+"\n")
        for i in range(20):
            print "yielding"
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(1)
        print "I pretended to do the work :) "


app = wx.App()
MainWindow(None, -1, 'Application')
app.MainLoop()
```

However, under Windows, the dialog box does not appear until after 20 yieldings have been printed - which starts immediately upon pressing the button - and the GUI is unresponsive during that time.

Have I misunderstood what to expect from `wx.Yield()`?

Comment: I've discovered that it appears that MessageBox is "causing" the problem on Windows.   The code gets to printing "requested work start", but before the message box appears, the CallAfter of DoTheWork starts running, and during this it does not yeild.  It's as if calling MessageBox lets other wx Events in first.  If I comment out the MessageBox, the CallAfter runs _after_ printing "registered the CallAfter", and the yield works.   Is this a bug/misbehaviour of MessageBox under Windows?

Comment: Removing the line wx.MessageBox('Job Submitted') allows the application to function correctly on Windows. On OSX the application waits for the user to press OK on the popup MessageBox, but on Windows the application just seems to run right past it, screwing it. No idea why though!

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep in mind that wxPython wraps the native widgets on each OS. If the native widget has a different behavior on Windows than it does on Linux or Mac, then that may actually be normal for that OS. I am guessing that is what is happening here. A simple workaround is to just switch to a wx.MessageDialog that you can show modally. So swap out the line where you create the wx.MessageBox with these two:

```
msg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Job Submitted', "Job", wx.OK)
msg.ShowModal()
```

Comment: I'm sure that a modal dialog box is what's intended - thanks!   (This is someone else's code that I'm helping debug :) )

Comment: Probably. If you want to "pause" execution, you definitely need to show a Dialog modally.

Comment: Thinking about it - the intent isn't to pause execution though.   The long running task is fine to get going in the background, behind the non-modal message.   More importantly, irrespective of intent, this stil seems like buggy behaviour - it' not just "different" - the yield is not causing the MessageBox to be able to be displayed.   It's as though "CallAfter" is behaving like "call now" - IE OnSubmit the event handler flow of execution does not appear to get to the MessageBox line in `OnSubmit`.   Surely you would expect it to?   I think that this is the core of my question.

Comment: I think the problem may lie in where you have CallAfter. If you want the CallAfter to work AFTER the MessageBox, then maybe you should call it after you have displayed it. As it is, you tell the Running pane to start working and THEN show the message box. On Windows, it's already started working and blocking the main loop with its time.sleep(), so the message box can't show itself. At least, that's my interpretation. When you block it modally, it can't do that.

Comment: This is where I had thought yield comes in.  Why doesn't the yield between sleeps let the MessageBox (and the rest of the GUI) operate?  (as it does in OSX)?

Comment: You would need to ask on the wxPython Google group for the definitive answer as I'm not sure